# Django pagination error, int has no len

Tags: django, pagination

```
@csrf_exempt
def board_searched(request):
    searchStr = request.GET['searchStr']
    pageForView = request.GET['pageForView']
    contact_list = Board.objects.filter(title__contains=searchStr).count()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 10)  # Show 25 contacts per page

    contacts = paginator.page(1)


return render(request, 'board/board_searched.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

This views.py code, that processing search in board.
And I give the link 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/board/search/result/?searchStr=asd&pageForView=1

In this case, It occurred `object of type 'int' has no len()`

And, It occurred at

```
contacts = paginator.page(1)
```

What is the problem..?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `count()` here:

```
contact_list = Board.objects.filter(title__contains=searchStr).count()
```

It should be:

```
contact_list = Board.objects.filter(title__contains=searchStr)
```

You have to provide the queryset, and then the amount you want returned. Before, you were not passing a queryset, only a number, which is invalid.